# What is the best way to include huge json into node.js script?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How to include huge json file (550MB) into node.js script?

I tried:

```
var json = require('./huge-data-set.json')
```

The script was executed with increased --max-old-space-size parameter

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 diff.js
```

it failed with:

```
buffer.js:500
    throw new Error('"toString()" failed');
    ^

Error: "toString()" failed
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:500:11)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:552:33)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:556:20)
```

Comment: two things: Have you tried running it with a small data-set to see if the size of your .JSON is the problem? And if not, can you post the code relevant to the error?

Comment: Maybe the JSON isn't valid?

Comment: Ugh, I'm not sure how many parsers are prepared to work with 500 meg of XML, which _should_ be heavier in general. 500 meg of JSON is quite a lot.

Comment: The script with only the first line that requires json results in error.
Usually, i split big json files with node, but this time i cannot load anything.

Comment: This may solve your problem: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Behind Node is v8 engine implementing JS implementation. V8 is written in c++ and as a result it uses types to save its characters in strings *(sarcasm used with caution here)*.

As specified by ECMA JavaScript stores every character on two bytes (utf16 encoded).

> The String type is the set of all ordered sequences of zero or more
>   16-bit unsigned integer values (“elements”) up to a maximum length of
>   2^53-1 elements

so what you are experiencing is not an out of memory limit, but instead a failed operation since the string is larger than the bytes size of the string type.

if you try to write the json object in javascript instead of reading it from fs (by requiring it), you will have an out of memory exception then, since the limit is set to prevent such cases from happening.

Comment: this answer is more helpful in improving understanding of the problem while the comment from @Paulpro was helpful in solving the same

Answer (score 2):

The error arises because you're trying to create a (single) string that is too large.

Some possible solutions:

- Use a different backing store (e.g. sqlite db) and query data as you need instead of loading it all into memory at once
- If your data is an array at the top level, consider having each array element on a separate line, that way you can just buffer a line and `JSON.parse()` that, then continue to the next line. However, you could still run into memory/GC issues if the parsed JavaScript values eat up too much space.

Comment: Are the any ways to increase default limit for strings? In the past i successfully loaded about 250mb files.

Comment: @user1276919 I don't think that JSON is meant to be used as a big data storage. I suggest that you don't modify limits in all sort of ways, since you will struggle to make it work on another machine. Even an update of Node.js may be able to break your script if you tweak the thing too much.